# Understanding sample complexity in the context of uniform convergence

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-learning

I was reading [Andrew Ng's notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes4.pdf) and on page 6 he mentions (uniform convergence):

$$Pr[\forall h \in \mathcal{H}_{finite}|\epsilon(h_i)-\hat{\epsilon}(h_j)| \leq \gamma] 
\geq 1-2ke^{-2\gamma^2m}$$

where $\hat\epsilon(h_i) = \frac{1}{m}\sum^{m}_{j=1}Z_j$ and $Z_{j}$ is a drawn example ${(X_i, Y_i)}$ and $\epsilon(h)$ is generalization/true error of the current h. He says:

> Given $\gamma$ and some $\delta> 0$, how large must m be before we can
>   guarantee that with probability at least $1 − \delta$, training error will be
>   within $\gamma$ of generalization error? By setting $\delta = 2\gamma e^{−2\gamma^2m}$ and
>   solving for m, [you should convince yourself this is the right thing
>   to do!]

I guess what I am unsure about is that part where he says we should be convinced that "its the correct thing to do." Can someone explain to me **why** thats the correct thing to do? I guess I don't really understand the reasoning on how to get the sample complexity. Why is it that if we set to $\delta$ and then rearrange terms, then that is exactly the minimum number of samples in order to achieve a certain level of performance.

I do understand that if you set $\delta = 2\gamma e^{−2\gamma^2m}$ by algebra you get:

$$m = \frac{1}{2\gamma^2}\log{\frac{2k}{\delta}}$$

However, I do not understand how or **why** it becomes:

$$m \geq \frac{1}{2\gamma^2}\log{\frac{2k}{\delta}}$$

How does the equality becomes an inequality? i.e. I understand the algebra, but not the motivation for such algebra and its relation the sample complexity and generalization guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $δ=2k e^{−2γ^2m}$ (you made a small typo), $\mathrm P[ |ϵ(h_i)−\hat ϵ(h_j)|≤γ] ≥1−δ$, as desired ("we can guarantee that with probability at least 1−δ"). If $m' > \frac{1}{2γ^2} \log\frac{2k}{δ}$, then $δ' \equiv 2k e^{−2γ^2m'} < δ$, **so the probability is even closer to unity** (the concentration bound is tighter).

Comment: Hello @emre can you please guide me that whats the difference between sample complexiy and uniform convergence. both seems same in this document